# how can I create a table in Vertica with receiving time?

Tags: sql, timestamp, default, vertica

I get weather telemetries from Kafka and insert it to Vertica.
I want to add to the vertica table a `'receive_time'` type `timestamp` column and `'receive_date'` type `date` column that indicate the exact time a telemetry was been inserted to the table.

this is my creation statement for example:

```
CREATE TABLE my_scheme.weather
(
    location_id int NOT NULL,
    humidity float,
    current_temp float,
    wind_speed float,
    wind_direction varchar(100),
    feels_like float,
    latitude float,
    longitude float,
    current_condition varchar(100)
);
```

how to add `'receive_time'` and `'receive_date'` columns that get the time from the Vertica? it is even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DEFAULT` expression to set the default value of a column as `sysdate`.

```
CREATE TABLE my_scheme.weather
(
    location_id int NOT NULL,
    humidity float,
    current_temp float,
    wind_speed float,
    wind_direction varchar(100),
    feels_like float,
    latitude float,
    longitude float,
    current_condition varchar(100),
    receive_datetime TIMESTAMP DEFAULT sysdate
);
```

For further read:
https://forum.vertica.com/discussion/240077/default-a-column-s-value